# Cumulative sum of a column in two different positive and negative directions

Tags: sql, cumulative-sum

how can I get desired result.
I want to calculate the cumulative sum of negative numbers first and then add this cumulative sum with positive numbers.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tb(
    [group_name] [nvarchar](255) 
    ,[value] [float] 
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tb]
           ([group_name]
           ,[value])
     VALUES
           ('A',-3),('A',-2),('A',-1),('A',1),('A',3),('B',-2)
```

By writing the following code, the result column will be displayed

```
SELECT [group_name]
      ,[value]
      ,sum(value) OVER (PARTITION BY group_name ORDER BY value asc ) result
  FROM [dbo].[tb]
```

How can I achieve the desired column?

| group_name | value | result | desired |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | -3 | -3 | -6 |
| A | -2 | -5 | -3 |
| A | -1 | -6 | -1 |
| A | 1 | -5 | 0 |
| A | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| B | -2 | -2 | -2 |

Comment: After the desired value reaches 0, I think the desired should be 4 (1+3), right?

Comment: No.Proccess is like this
-1 will be -1.  Then
-2 will be (-1+ -2)=-3.  Then -3 will be (-3+ -3)=-6.     In other direction we start with first cumulative value of negative numbers =-1.  1 will be (1+ -1)=0.   3 will be (3+0)=3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use conditional sum window function as the following:

```
SELECT group_name, value,
       CASE 
         WHEN 
          value<0 THEN
            SUM(CASE WHEN value<0 THEN value END) OVER 
            (PARTITION BY group_name ORDER BY value DESC)
          ELSE
            SUM(CASE WHEN value>=0 THEN value END) OVER 
            (PARTITION BY group_name ORDER BY value) + 
            MAX(CASE WHEN value<0 THEN value END) OVER 
            (PARTITION BY group_name)
       END AS desired
FROM tb
ORDER BY group_name, value
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/E-w0uvnj).

Answer (score 1):

Similar idea to @ahmed, but refactored using `cte`, `sign()`, and `abs`

```
with cte as
(select group_name,
        value, 
        sum(value) over (partition by group_name, sign(value) order by abs(value)) as sum,
        max(case when value<0 then value end) over (partition by group_name) as max_neg
 from your_table)
  
select *, case when value<0 then sum else sum+max_neg end as final_sum
from cte
```